# DRY models usable by both Mongoose and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, restangular

I am writing a MEAN app, using Mongoose to communicate with MongoDB and Restangular to communicate with Express. My Mongoose model definitions currently live in the server directory because, well, they're for Mongoose. On the Angular side I'm just manipulating raw JSON and letting Restangular/Mongoose sort out the details.

For a variety of reasons, most of them self-evident, I'd like to stop working with JSON directly and start using model classes. One major reason is I'm finding the need for helper functions from which both server and client would benefit.

The knee-jerk solution would be to create front-end class equivalents of whatever models are server-side. That leads to serious code duplication.

The smarter (?) idea would be to expose models to both server and client. First off, I'm not sure of the security implications. Second, as the model stands currently, it's not Angular friendly. My model design looks very much like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235386/260460).

Is there any refactoring I can do to make one set of classes consumable by Angular and Mongoose?

**EDIT:** To clarify current design and to clarify where I would like to go, consider this snippet. DB data—say, `[{ u: "LON" }, { u: "PAR" }]`—is bound to a d3 selection and circles are drawn by deriving X/Y coordinates from an existing dictionary and the property `u`.

```
var centroids = { "lon": [100, 200], "par": [43, 139], "stp": [12, 121] };
svg.selectAll('circle')
     .data(dbData)
     .enter()
     .append('circle')
     .attr('cx', function(d) { return centroids[d.u.toLowerCase()][0]; })
     .attr('cy', function(d) { return centroids[d.u.toLowerCase()][1]; })
     .attr('fill', 'red')
     .attr('r', 20);
```

It works. But what if I used a class fleshed out with helper methods?

```
var centroids = { "lon": [100, 200], "par": [43, 139], "stp": [12, 121] };
svg.selectAll('circle')
     .data(dbData)
     .enter()
     .append('circle')
     .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.getXCoordinate(centroids); })
     .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.getYCoordinate(centroids); })
     .attr('fill', d.ageIsDivisbleBy6() ? 'red' : 'purple')
     .attr('r', 20);
```

So much more readable. Hopefully this clarifies my goal: I could write a client-side version of the models Mongoose uses, but if I can, I'd rather have Mongoose and the client operate on the same set of models.

Comment: what on earth does `model isn't angular friendly` mean?  or `stop working with JSON directly`? Question is really hard to interpret. Code samples would help

Comment: Regarding 'angular friendly', follow the link for a code sample: my models look almost exactly like that, one model per file. I don't think it would work just including the model file in index.html and tweaking Restangular to return instances of that model.

Regarding 'stop working with JSON', Express generates JSON, and Restangular turns that into generic JS objects. It's fine for basic reads of properties, but I don't get any functional or design benefits that come with working with class instances. I'll post an example in the body.

Comment: I suspect you come from a class oriented programming background like Java. javascript doesn't need or have classes, or variable types defined. You have to send JSON to front end but it's not hard either to load a model config. I don't see how you plan to share params like `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` with angular . No idea what problems you are having with restangular because it is highly extendable. Again, show some practical examples of what you would like to see shared

Comment: @charlietfl: How I handle ObjectId is a valid point, which is why I asked the core question of what refactoring (if any) could be done to make as much of these models—properties, prototype methods, whatever—available to Mongoose and Angular. The more I can share, the less duplicated code. Restangular is not the problem: if I can find a design that works, Restangular can be configured appropriately, as you say.

Comment: What you probably want to look into is writing a node module that would allow you to share helpers, configs etc. I would retag this `node` , that's not really my strong suit