# Using a Mongoose model defined in another file returns Undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It seems pretty clear that defining a model in one file but using it in another is common practice. I don't know why I'm having so much trouble getting it to work. I spent the morning rewriting my simple MongoDB app to follow what I thought was a [dead simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230932/file-structure-of-mongoose-nodejs-project?rq=1). I'm just structuring it like the top answer with the added convenience that the file where I define the Schema and Model and access the Model are in the same folder (because the project is so small and I'm just learning MongoDB). I think part of the problem as I tried researching solutions is that other examples really complex to follow. The DB connects as expected and I can work in the `ManageDB.js` file fine, but of course want to keep the project organized, even at my small scale. (The server.js file in the directory above connects before this code executes.)

What other things can I try to troubleshoot this MongoDB application?

```
// src/ManageDB.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const devTweetRecordsModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    time: Date,
    text: String,
    source: String,
    positive: Number,
    negative: Number,
});
var tweetdb = mongoose.model('DevTweetDB', devTweetRecordsModel);

module.exports = {
    tweetdb: tweetdb
};


// src/TwitterAPI.js
    
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var tweetdb = require('../src/ManageDB').tweetdb;

console.log(tweetdb); // Returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

After defining a model-schema in mongoose you should assign it as mongoose.model
as you can see in the documentation.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

When you call mongoose.model() on a schema, Mongoose compiles a model for you.
and then you can use it by requiring it in another file.

```js
const Model= require('./../models/modelName');
```

Comment: Even though this is slightly shorter carefully checking my example against your suggestion is still returning `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a way I hadn't seen suggested anywhere so I will post here for completeness. The solution was very sensitivity to how I exported it and brought it into the other JS file.

```
// Model.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('DevTweetDB', devTweetRecordsModel);

// TwitterAPI.js
var tweetdb = require('../models/tweetdb');
console.log(tweetdb);

// Returns the object as expected:
// Model { DevTweetDB }
```