# Mongoose model from another file returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write MVC in nodejs. The problem is, that render method returns undefined, instead of database data. But if I call

```
Website.find({}, function(err, docs) {
     res.send(`docs`);
    })
```

direct from index.js - it works just fine, am I doing something wrong?

index.js:

```
app.get('/websites', (req, res) => {

const View       = require("./views/websitesView");
const Controller = require("./controllers/websitesController");
const Model      = require("./models/websiteModel");

var model      = new Model();
var controller = new Controller(model);
var view       = new View(controller);


res.send(view.render(req, res));
})
```

view.js:

```
var controller = require("../controllers/websitesController");

class websitesView {
  controller;

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  setTab(tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
  }
  render(req, res) {

      res.send(`${this.controller.getAllWebsites()}`);

  }
}

module.exports = websitesView;
```

controller.js:

```
const Website = require("../models/websiteModel");


class websitesController {
  model;

  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  getAllWebsites() {
    Website.find({}, function(err, docs) {
     return docs;
    })
  }

}

module.exports = websitesController;
```

model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const websiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: String,
  user_id: String,
  type: String,
  status: Number,
  timestamp: Date
}, {collection: "aaa_websites"})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Website", websiteSchema, 'aaa_websites')
```

[Using a Mongoose model defined in another file returns Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031994/using-a-mongoose-model-defined-in-another-file-returns-undefined) didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

index.js:

```
app.get('/websites', async (req, res) => {

 const View       = require("./views/websitesView");
 const Controller = require("./controllers/websitesController");
 const Model      = require("./models/websiteModel");


 var controller = new Controller(Model);
 var view       = new View(controller);

 res.send(await view.render(req, res));
})
```

view.js:

```
var controller = require("../controllers/websitesController");

class websitesView {
  controller;

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  setTab(tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
  }
  async render(req, res) {
      res.send(`${await this.controller.getAllWebsites()}`);
  }
}

module.exports = websitesView;
```

controller.js:

```
class websitesController {
  model;

  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  async getAllWebsites() {
    return this.model.find({})
  }

}

module.exports = websitesController;
```

Comment: it does work, thank you, I guess I need to learn await / async first

Comment: Not only that, why you initialize the model ‘ var model      = new Model();’